# *** changed into files when using cut-command

Tags: bash, cut

I read a record from a file which contains the following value :

```
    1907;1193;2317;COMMENT;TAG: *** REASON : Circumvention *** SSC
```

I want to split up this record into several variables :

```
       rowId=$(echo $record | cut -d ';' -f1)
       columnId=$(echo $record | cut -d ';' -f3) 
       columnName=$(echo $record | cut -d ';' -f4) 
       dataValue=$(echo $record | cut -d ';' -f5)
```

The first 3 variables contains the right values but the variable `"dataValue"` contains :

```
    TAG: testfile.txt test.sh tst.sh REASON : Circumvention compareTxtFiles.sh testfile.txt test.sh tst.sh SSC
```

In other words the system changed the "***" into the files residing on my home-directory.
How can I avoid this and keep the text as it should be ?

Comment: See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
record="1907;1193;2317;COMMENT;TAG: *** REASON : Circumvention *** SSC"
dataValue=$(echo "$record" | cut -d ';' -f5)
echo "$dataValue"
```